# Extent Report Selenium WebDriver Screenshot Loading Issue c#

Tags: c#, screenshot, relative-path, selenium-extent-report

I am using below code to save the screenshot to the same folder (d:\DevTeam\LSPTestSuites) as my reports HTML file.

```
ScreenshotFilePath = $"{Reporter.LatestResultsReportFolder}\\{screenshotName}.jpg";
ScreenshotFilePath = ScreenshotFilePath.Replace('/', ' ').Replace('"', ' ');
ss.SaveAsFile(ScreenshotFilePath, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
```

but the screenshots don't load if I copy the folder to another location.

The complete screenshot file path saved in the report.html file is as follows:

```
<td class='step-details'>Launch Introductory Video.<img data-featherlight='d:\DevTeam\LSPTestSuites\20181128_1135\PASSED_STEP_TCID31906a_Launch Introductory Video..jpg' class='step-img' src='d:\DevTeam\LSPTestSuites\20181128_1135\PASSED_STEP_TCID31906a_Launch Introductory Video..jpg' data-src='d:\DevTeam\LSPTestSuites\20181128_1135\PASSED_STEP_TCID31906a_Launch Introductory Video..jpg'></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I saved the screenshot to the screenshots folder inside the reports directory (c://temp/LSPTestSuites/screenshots) then, I removed the reports directory path from the screenshot file path and later used it to add it to the report.

```
ScreenshotFilePath = $"{Reporter.LatestResultsReportFolder}\\screenshots\\{screenshotName}.jpg";
ScreenshotFilePath = ScreenshotFilePath.Replace('/', ' ').Replace('"', ' ');
ss.SaveAsFile(ScreenshotFilePath, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
//to save relative screenshots in Reports html file - start
if(ScreenshotFilePath.IndexOf("screenshots") != -1)
{
       ScreenshotFilePath = ScreenshotFilePath.Substring(ScreenshotFilePath.IndexOf("screenshots"));
}
//to save relative screenshots in Reports html file - end
Logger.Trace($"ScreenshotFilePath => {ScreenshotFilePath}");
```

The key was to use relative path (screenshots/screenshot.png) while adding the screenshot to the extent report:

```
CurrentTestCase.AddScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath);
```

Now, I can move the reports folder to any location to any machine and the screenshots are loaded/displayed without any issues.

Comment: Solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

Once you have "Screenshots" folder(on root location) in your Current project directory, You can get it by :

```
    //Set Current Project directory
    public static String dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    public static FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(dir);
    public static DirectoryInfo currentDir = fileInfo.Directory.Parent.Parent;
    public static string parentDirName = currentDir.FullName;

    //Save screenshot
    Screenshot file = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
    file.SaveAsFile(parentDirName + "\\Screenshots\\" + "Tempname.png", ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);

    //To load it for Selenium Extent Report
    testlog.Info("Details with screenshot" ,  MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromPath(parentDirName + "\\Screenshots\\" + "Tempname.png").Build());
```

Comment: I have to save the testresults and screenshots to a d:\DevTeam\LSPTestSuites folder on teamcity server. Then, I would like to copy them and save to my pc. The problem is that when I save them to my pc let's say to c:\ the screenshots don't load as their saved location in html remains d:\DevTeam\LSPTestSuites\20181128_1135\screenshot.jpg I need a solution so that the saved location for screenshots in html file is relative to the html file location something like PASSED_STEP_TCID31906a_Launch Introductory Video..jpg or \screenshots\screenshot.jpg

Comment: I am still not clear with your actual issue, Do you able to save screenshot on your both mentioned location ?

Comment: I am able to save screenshot at my desired location such as D:\DevTeam\LSPTestSuites\20181128_1135\screenshots\screenshot1....jpg and so on. My report is at the following location: d:\DevTeam\LSPTestSuites\20181128_1135\TestResults.html When I Copy\move the 20181128_1135 folder with screenshots and TestResults.html to another location let's say C:\20181128_1135\screenshots  and launch  TestResults.html from C:\20181128_1135\TestResults.html the screenshots don't load as they are still pointing to D:\DevTeam\LSPTestSuites\20181128_1135\screenshots\ in the TestResults.html file.

Comment: It is simple, .HTML made with image path. Path contains link of given location. Your moving action doesn't change the path which is given to image in HTML report. Hope it makes clear.